# jQuery SUM doubling values

Tags: jquery

I want to do to collect all the values ​​from the all select menus. but When choosing a decimal number not correctly added.

#### jQuery code:

```
var total = 0;

function calcTotal()
{
    $("input:checked,select").each(function()
    {
        //This happens for each checked input field
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        total += parseInt(value); 
        var prog = $('select[name="prog"] option:selected').text();
        $("#prog1").val(prog);

        var ticket = $('select[name="ticket"] option:selected').text();
        $("#ticket1").val(ticket);

        var skn = $('select[name="skn"] option:selected').text();
        $("#skn1").val(skn);

        var buy = $('input[name=buy]:checked').text()
        $("#buy1").val(buy);
    });
}

//This happens when the page loads
calcTotal();    
$("#total").val(total); 

$("input:checkbox, input:radio,select,selected").click(function()
{
    total = 0;
    calcTotal();

    $("#total").val(total);
});
```

#### HTML code:

```
<form method="POST" >
    <select name="logah" style="padding: 3px;">
        <option value="0">--</option>
        <option value="1"  >1</option>
        <option value="1.5"  >1.5</option>
        <option value="2.5" >2.5</option>
    </select>

    <select name="select2" style="padding: 3px;">
        <option value="0">--</option>
        <option value="1"  >1</option>
        <option value="2" >6</option>
    </select>
```

I want to sum all values from select menu.

Comment: How you sum your value using jquery. please post you jquery code??

Comment: Please post further details about your scenario, what jQuery have you tried and what result are you currently getting?

Comment: i think parseInt dosen't works with decimal values

Comment: Please don't use plz.

Answer (score 2):

You try to parse numbers with [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function, which only parses Integer values (..., -1 0, 1, 2, 3 ...). Change it to [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), and it should work.

Other way is to just add that string, which would be converted to number when added to other number:

```
0 + "1.5" => 1.5   (number)
"" + "1.5 => "1.5" (string)
```